# One jsp for both add and update functionality

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller, java-7

This might be very basic question and but still want to know which could be better approach in terms of performance and maintainability.

1. i have page where i need to add and update functionality,  and i have handled it in same jsp for

> eg:- manageCouriers.jsp

, but here i have to write more code to check whether it is update or add action and also in controller (i am using spring mvc).

2. if i use separate jsp for

> eg:- addCourier.jsp and updateCourier.jsp

, here for me it is straight forward, i dont want to check any condition, here i need less coding, and i see both page will have same attribute most cases, but i get hit in maintaining both pages if there are future changes.

i feel both scenarios seems be better some ways, i am in state of confusion which one to choose, for better performance and maintainability. Thanks for your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

Start with the least common denominator that supports all your current and future forseable use-cases, and refactor when/if new requirements force you to.

That said, from what you've described, the easiest at least from the maintenence point of view would be to have a single form, with two buttons with `name` attribute so that you can easily distinguish server methods based on `param` attribute of the `@RequestMapping`, something like

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="add" value="add"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="update"/>
```

and distinguish your conroller methods based on the param e.g. for edit

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "add")
public String add() {
...  
}
```

and for update

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "update")
public String update() {
...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid duplication, for flexibility make two pages but use jsp include for common shared parts, code is duplicated only in deployed JSP java classes so maintenance is easier on the JSP side and performance is the same.

```
<%@include file="common.inc"%>
```

The more logic you do in controller the better, make available the results in the model and just read them in the JSP.

For example you could decide to signal to the `common.inc` if the page is an insert or an update both in controller (better) or in JSP (hardcoded in each of the two pages or may be even in `common.inc` checking if ID is present or not)

I agree that you should avoid to make checks in JSP however the more complete the "common" jsp code is, more inevitable will be doing checks like <c:if> or <c:when> (not that bad as long as you are just checking presentation logic, eg: if `isEdit=true` then print different header label)